# AngularJS ngRoute - specify data for target page, with data not appearing in URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using AngularJS and I would like to redirect a user when he clicks a button on /page1 to /page2. I currently use AngularJS routing for this using ngRoute which works all fine. However, in addition to the redirection, I would also like to pass some data from page1 to page2 to pre-populate some of the HTML on page2. I know that in order to pass such data, I can either specify it in the path parameter,e.g.

```
/page2/<param1>/<param2>
```

or as a query string parameter, e.g.

```
 /page2?<key1>=<value1>&<key2=value2>
```

In both ways, I can retrieve the query string or path params in /page2 using `$route.current.params`

However, I do not want to do either of the above as I do not want to expose my data on the URL to the user. Is there a way in AngularJS that the parameters can be passed to /page2, such that they are "hidden" from the URL?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a service to store data that will survive route changes. Services are singletons that persist through the entire life of the app. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services).

Comment: thanks, using a service worked! if you can add an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to store data that will survive route changes. Services are singletons that persist through the entire life of the app.

```
app.service("appData", function() {
    var myData;
    this.set = function(data) {
        myData = data;
    };
    this.get = function() {
        return myData;
    };
}
```

In a controller:

```
app.controller("viewCtrl", function($scope,appData) {
    $scope.myData = appData.get();

    //

    appData.set(newData);

});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services).